# Spring HATEOS paging response object is showing incorrect last link

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am trying to build custom response object, but in the final response i am getting incorrect link for **last** element.

Any thought ?

Request :`/searchx?page=2&size=5&total_required=true`

Response :

```
 "_links": {
    "first": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/xx/fxy/x1/searchx?total_required=true&page=0&size=5"
    },
    "prev": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/xx/fxy/x1/searchx?total_required=true&page=1&size=5"
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/xx/fxy/x1/searchx?total_required=true&page=2&size=5"
    },
    "last": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/xx/fxy/x1/searchx?total_required=true&page=2&size=5"
    }
},
```

Here is the my page resource assembler.

```html
        Page<MyData> pageRs = new PageImpl<>(data, pageable, total);

    response.setData(pageRs.getContent());
    PagedModel<MyModel> responseModels = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(pageRs, datAssembler);
    response.setLinks(responseModels.getLinks());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the total elements count in **PageImpl** class argument. After fixing that i was able to get correct page links.